# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name

Tags: magento2.3.7

I need help with that if i want to install module i get error after make command php bin/upgrade

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'GHMZ_AMASTY_AMCHKT_FIELD_ATTR_ID_GHMZ_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID', query was: ALTER TABLE `ghmz_amasty_amcheckout_field` MODIFY COLUMN `id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity ID", MODIFY COLUMN `attribute_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT "EAV Attribute ID", MODIFY COLUMN `sort_order` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT "Sort Order", MODIFY COLUMN `width` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT "Width", MODIFY COLUMN `store_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Store Id", ADD CONSTRAINT `GHMZ_AMASTY_AMCHKT_FIELD_ATTR_ID_GHMZ_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `ghmz_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE, DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8', DEFAULT COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the **db_schema_whitelist.json** for that particular Moudle.

Below command will help you to generate the same file.

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist Vendor_ModuleName
```

After that **check the etc folder** of same module, there one file name : **db_schema_whitelist.json will be generated**.

After that run cache flush and then run the setup upgrade command.